# Can a single item from a specified index be retrieved from a stringCollection using a claims transformation?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

[GetSingleItemFromStringCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations#getsingleitemfromstringcollection) exists, but it only allows retrieval of the first item in a collection. Is there a way to retrieve an element at a specified index?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the collection and index to a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-intro) and let the API extract the required item.

Comment: You are correct, but I was hoping there was a native way to do this with a simple claims transformation

Comment: @DanielKrasnove did you have a native way to do it?