# Extracting Country Code from Mobile Number in Azure B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am currently working on an Azure B2C custom policy and I need to extract the country code from a user's mobile number attribute ("mobilePhone") in each user record. The mobile number is stored in the format "+852 91031201" (including the country code). My goal is to retrieve the country code separately for further processing.

I would like to know the best approach to achieve this within an Azure B2C custom policy. Are there any built-in functions or methods that can help me extract the country code from the mobile number attribute? If not, what would be the most efficient and reliable way to accomplish this task?

Comment: And then I discovered https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-number-claims-transformations#getnationalnumberandcountrycodefromphonenumberstring

Answer (score 1):

You could do a [StringSplit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#example-of-stringsplit) if there is a space.

And then a [GetSingleItemFromStringCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations#example-of-getsingleitemfromstringcollection) to get the first element, i.e. the country code.

If there is no space, then because country codes are varying lengths, call a REST API that uses a library to do this. There are a number online.

Comment: Want to ask one more question.
You know how can we make the "-" to be another ClaimType for the following?

Example of StringReplace
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations

Comment: Sorry - don't understand.

Comment: Same problem with this one.
How can we get a single item from a specified index be retrieved from a stringCollection using a claims transformation without API (native way)?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66971608/can-a-single-item-from-a-specified-index-be-retrieved-from-a-stringcollection-us

Comment: You can't. You can only get the first. This is because B2C has no concept of looping.

Comment: is that mean i have no way to get the 2nd string from StringCollection?

Comment: Correct - unless you use an API to parse it.